# NoClassDefFoundError although OSGi bundle is there

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I get a run time error when trying to run a grails application on Eclipse Equinox.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/Transformer

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)

at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)

at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)

at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:481)

at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:469)

at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:449)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

The problem is that my bundle is importing the following package `com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections; version="3.2.1"`
When searching spring EBR I find that the bundle contains the required Class.

I used monitor tool to make sure that the bundle is running.

What can be the problem ?

Regards ?

Comment: Have you installed the Spring collections bundle into your OSGi runtime?

Comment: Do you have the package name ? I hav installed many things with it but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, you are importing the package **com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections**, but that is a a Spring built OSGi version of the **org.apache.commons.collections** jar file.  It is a bundle, not a package.

Your bundle would have to import **org.apache.commons.collections**, which is provided by the **com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections** bundle.  Assuming you are already supplying the Spring bundle to the runtime, you simply need to fix the import statement.

In your existing manifest, change (under your Import-Package section):

```
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections;version="3.2.1"
```

to

```
org.apache.commons.collections;version="3.2.1"
```

Comment: In my Manifest I have this in import statement com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections;version=
 "3.2.1". I installed the jar file which i got from spring EBR

Comment: @Houcem - That is your problem, the import should be as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your bundle **cannot** import the package `com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections` because there is no such package. What you probably mean is that you have installed the **bundle** with that name.

The error means that your bundle does not import the package `org.apache.commons.collections`, i.e. it must appear somewhere in the `Import-Package` statement of your bundle.

Comment: It appears in import package. I get this error in runtime and not when installing my bundle.

Comment: Of course; it's impossible to get such an error when installing a bundle. Hmm if the package does appear in your `Import-Package` statement then NCDFE *should not* occur. Is it possible that another bundle is actually throwing this error, i.e. not the one you think it is?

Answer (score -1):

Adding commons-collections jar file to your build path will solve this issue.

Comment: I already added it. But the class loader looks into the class from bundles on OSGi and not from files in the lib directory